Make column header and cell widths responsive in Tanstack table in Next.js
In the code below, I'm using Tanstack v8 table to display data. The issue I'm encountering is that the last column is getting hidden. Upon inspection, I noticed a 15 rem margin from Tailwind CSS. Is there a way to configure the width as auto from configuraion so it become responsive?
This is the implementation of columns
const columns: ColumnDef<IUSER>[] = [
  {
    accessorKey: "name",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Name
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "location",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
         Location
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "gender",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Gender
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "accCreationDate",
    cell: (props) => <span>{formatDateValue(props.getValue())}</span>,
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Created Date
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "uniqueId",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Unique Id
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "email",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Email
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
 {
    accessorKey: "number",
    header: ({ column }) => {
      return (
        <Button
          variant="ghost"
          onClick={() => column.toggleSorting(column.getIsSorted() === "asc")}
        >
          Contact No
          {column.getIsSorted() === "asc" ? <ChevronUp /> : <ChevronDown />}
        </Button>
      );
    },
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "id",
    header: "Action",
    cell: (rowData) => {
      const { id } = rowData.row.original as IUSER;
      return (
        <Link href={`/details/${id}`} className="text-blue-600">
          View Details
        </Link>
      );
    },
  },
];

This is the implementation of useReactTable.
 const table = useReactTable({
       data,
       columns,
       getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
       onSortingChange: setSorting,
       getSortedRowModel: getSortedRowModel(),
       state: {
         sorting,
      },
 });

return (
<div className="rounded-md border">
  <Table>
    <TableHeader className={"bg-slate-200"}>
      {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
        <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
          {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
            return (
              <TableHead key={header.id}>
                {header.isPlaceholder
                  ? null
                  : flexRender(
                    header.column.columnDef.header,
                    header.getContext(),
                  )}
              </TableHead>
            );
          })}
        </TableRow>
      ))}
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
      {table.getRowModel()?.rows?.length ? (
        table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
          <TableRow
            key={row.id}
            data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
          >
            {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
              <TableCell key={cell.id} className={"pl-8"}>
                {flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
          </TableRow>
        ))
      ) : (
        <TableRow>
          <TableCell colSpan={columns.length} className="h-24 text-center">
            No Data
          </TableCell>
        </TableRow>
      )}
    </TableBody>
  </Table>
</div>
 );


Can you please provide your column option?

@PinalTilva Updated in the description
